# Multi host Container communication with kubernetes and flannel

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flannel

I am following the following guide

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/flannel_multi_node_cluster.html

I get all the way to the very last step when it says to ping a container on another host from a separate container on another host.  I am supposed to see something like this (like it shows in the documentation)

```
bash-4.3# ping 18.16.90.4
PING 18.16.90.4 (18.16.90.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 18.16.90.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from 18.16.90.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.372 ms
```

I get no response on the ping, I don't know how to troubleshoot this and where I should start.

Comment: Turns out I needed to remove the old docker0 bridge from the original install and setup then reboot the daemons both flanneld and dockers.  This regenerated the bridges and added the --bip argument to the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to ping the container IP from outside the container, but on a different machine.  Then try typical network debugging tools like 'traceroute', make sure traffic is getting into the flannel bridge.

Also, use 'ifconfig' to make sure that the settings for the docker0 bridge match the settings that flannel created in its config file.